# Compare php MySQL query result arrays to get assosciated value from one of the arrays

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I have one set of results with selected player ID's, and another set of results of all playerID's and the price they will pay and I don't know how to combine the two.

I think the easiest way to explain is to show what I have done so far and what I'm trying to figure out.

I have an input form which gives a dropdown menu (event type) and a list of checkboxes for players:

Event type: Match

X = Player1    Junior

_ = Player2    Senior

X = Player3    Senior

Submitting this gets the player ID's which I can access with this:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
          echo $value;
          }
```

I can then using below query, retrieve the prices that each player within the club would pay for the event, based on the event type and the category of the player.

```
SELECT prices.price, book.id 
FROM prices 
JOIN book 
ON prices.cat = book.pricecat 
WHERE eventType = ?('$eventtype') AND clubID = ?('$clubID')
```

So now I have these two sets of results
One containing  the ID's of selected players.
The other containing all of the clubs playerID's and the Price to be paid for each.

How can I compare the two to get the prices for only the players selected?

Very new to PHP & SQL (4 long days of it!). I'm building the app for personal use and to trial it, need it done when hockey season starts in a week, so not had chance to learn properly from the beginning as I'd want to. Solved many problems but now my head hurts so I'll be very grateful for some advice on how I can solve this one!

Comment: Why don't you just add the users ID in the query and then you will get the prices for this IDs?

Comment: @AndréWalker The selected user ID's are results from another query and I don't know how to loop them into the newer query without repeating the query for each ID.

I think I may have figured it out now anyway. I didn't know much about associative arrays with keys and values, the one I show up there I copied from another question to get all of the $_POST values, so I think I can solve it by putting my query results into another assoc array and then using operators to compare the two.   :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your two sets of results into two arrays, and then loop through them.

```
$resultA = (firstset, with selected player names only);
$resultB = (secondset, with all the player names [0] and prices [1]);
$resultC = array();  // our final array that we'll build below

foreach ( $resultA as $selected )
{
   foreach ( $resultB as $player )
   {
      if ( $selected == $player[0] )
      {
         $resultC[] = $player;  // the "[]" adds an element to an array
      }
   }
}

var_dump($resultC);  // show us the final array
```